# searching for 3" in a string using InStr() vba

Tags: string, vba, search

I'm trying to search for a string which includes a doubel quote `"`. ex. search for the string 3" in the larger string `43-9120-BT-1207-3"-150H21-NI`. Currently this is what I have.

```
Dim line As String
line = "43-9120-BT-1207-3"-150H21-NI"

If InStr(1, line, Str$(34) & 3" & Str$(34)) > 0 Then
.
.
.
end if
```

I can never get into the if statement, tried many combinations of Str$(34)s and multiple "s but I get the error

Expected: List operator

Anyone can explain how to search for a string with a double quote at the end of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This  will find `3"` in your `line` string:

```
'assuming:
'activecell = 43-9120-BT-1207-3"-150H21-NI
'next:
line = activecell
'search for 3"
If InStr(1, line, "3" & Chr(34)) > 0 Then MsgBox "OK"
```

Comment: +1 and congrats on 10K I haven't even noticed when you've stepped up ;) congrats

Answer (score 0):

If the line is hardcoded, you need to escape it, by doubling the double quotes:

`line = "43-9120-BT-1207-3""-150H21-NI"`

Also these are double quotes `"`, these are single quotes `'`, you might want to change your question a bit.

**Edit :** correcting your second line as well.

`If InStr(1, line,  "3""" ) > 0 Then`

Comment: im using VLookup and it is returning the string, which I am saving into variable line.